# How to store String varables in an array from class to another in java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I explain this... well in my java program I have to classes one containing a dialog input and the other containing a string array.
In this program , when the user runs it , I would like the user to enter their name into the dialog input. when they enter their name i want it to be stored in a string array that is in another class and as soon as their name is stored in a variable i would like it to be printed in a console.. I hope this makes sense thank you.

Here is my work so far:

Class 1: getting the user's name

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Your Name:")
            {
                // This is where i am a bit stuck as i don't how to send
                        // the name variable to class 2 and store it in an array

            }
```

class 2: getting the name variable from class 1

```
   String []names = new  String[1];
public String getName()
{  
          return name; // not working as I am unable to retrieve the name variable
         // from class 1    
     }

      String []usernames {name};
      System.out.println(usernames); //trying print out the name that is entered.
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Why would you like to store the name inside an array in another class? I don't understand the goal :s

Comment: Why not use an `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: well basically the goal is to get the users name from class 1and print it out in class 2, so i thought an array would be the best thing to use?  store the users name and print it out?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you try to do but this could be an answer.

```
public class Storage{
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Storage storage = new Storage();
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Your Name:");
        storage.setName(name);

        [...]
        storage.getName(); // Give you the name
    }
}
```

But... why??

Comment: well basically the goal is to get the users name from class 1and print it out in class 2, so i thought an array would be the best thing to use?  store the users name and print it out?  Thank you

Comment: Not really, I suggest you to keep this solution for now and come back if you got another problem.